# Is there a downloadable Scipy file for Python 3.6

Tags: numpy, scipy, python-3.4, python-3.6

I have Python 3.6 and I was wondering if there is a downloadable scipy file for version 3.6. I opened up the command prompt and ran "py -m pip install scipy". And it just gives me an error. I know its not the pip because its already updated. When I did it for nltk and numpy it worked but it doesn't work for scipy. I read somewhere that you have to download and install 3.4 because scipy is not compatible with 3.6. Any answer would be very much appreciated thank you

Comment: I can install spicy for python 3.6 via Anaconda

Answer (score 1):

This is not python 3.6 specific. There are official manylinux1 and macOS wheels on pypi, so `pip install` should pick them. On Windows, you can use Christoph Gohlke wheels,

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

Or, as others noted, there are prebuilt packages for python 3.6 in the conda-land.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but i now use anaconda and this has it already installed.. as well as most science data modules..

https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with conda, there is one simple trick to know this...

type

`conda search scipy`

it will tell you the best combinations.

```
scipy                          1.4.1  py38h82752d6_0  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.4.1  py38hebbc057_0  pkgs/main           
scipy                          1.5.0  py36h1dac7e4_0  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.0  py36h912ce22_0  pkgs/main           
scipy                          1.5.0  py36hadf427e_0  pkgs/main           
scipy                          1.5.0  py36he995f2f_0  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.0  py37h912ce22_0  pkgs/main           
scipy                          1.5.0  py37hadf427e_0  pkgs/main           
scipy                          1.5.0  py37hce1b9e5_0  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.0  py38h38b60c6_0  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.0  py38h3eb1e28_0  pkgs/main           
scipy                          1.5.0  py38hbab996c_0  pkgs/main           
scipy                          1.5.1  py36h1dac7e4_0  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.1  py36he995f2f_0  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.1  py37hce1b9e5_0  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.1  py38h38b60c6_0  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.2  py36h01b1e2b_0  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.2  py36h01b1e2b_1  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.2  py36h01b1e2b_2  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.2  py36h3862da1_2  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.2  py36h61c6cb4_0  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.2  py36h61c6cb4_1  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.2  py36h61c6cb4_2  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.2  py36h912ce22_0  pkgs/main           
scipy                          1.5.2  py36haa79e3e_2  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.2  py36hadf427e_0  pkgs/main           
scipy                          1.5.2  py37h2702c91_0  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.2  py37h2702c91_1  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.2  py37h2702c91_2  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.2  py37h912ce22_0  pkgs/main           
scipy                          1.5.2  py37ha9eab96_2  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.2  py37hadf427e_0  pkgs/main           
scipy                          1.5.2  py38h1402333_0  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.2  py38h1402333_1  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.2  py38h1402333_2  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.2  py38h9bd2513_2  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.2  py39h27fd13a_1  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.2  py39h27fd13a_2  conda-forge         
scipy                          1.5.2  py39hea380fd_2  conda-forge
```

for example:

```
scipy                          1.5.2  py39
```